# include boost/thread.hpp can't startup

Tags: boost, boost-thread

if i #include  and not create any instance, compile success, but can't startup, the stack is:

```
   ntdll!RtlIpv4StringToAddressExW+0xb54c
   ntdll!RtlLockHeap+0x252
   Test!operator new+0xf
   Test!boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_>+0xb7
   Test!QueryPerformanceFrequency+0x16fa
   Test!_cinit+0x5e
   Test!WinMainCRTSartup+0x143
   kernel32!ProcessIDToSessionId+0x209
```

my environment is win7 x64 sp1 + vc71 + boost1.46(1.52 also test)
please help me.

Comment: What do you mean "can't startup"? It crashes? What's the error message?

Comment: yes, crash. error message is:  Faulting application Test.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.2.3790.4937, fault address 0x0004cd12.

Answer (score 0):

I replace boost/thread.hpp with boost/thread/thread.hpp fixed, buy why?